# View Models in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I was wondering if it is possible or how to be able to define a ViewModel in the Application module and pass it to display in the layout.phtml in Zend Framework 2. Here is the code for the Application Controller:

`namespace Application\Controller;`

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $container = new Container('session');

        return new ViewModel(array('username' => $container->username,
                                   'password' => $container->password));
    }
}

 This is the layout.phtml page I am trying to get username to display

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><p class="navbar-text" style="font-family: Papyrus, fantasy; font-size: 20px;">       
     <?php echo $username; ?></p></li> 
  </ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is where ViewHelpers come into play. The ViewHelper has access to the auth identity and then displays whatever you want to display.

Comment: one simple google search :S http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display anything in layout ViewModel which is called root ViewModel you should use your controller`s layout() plugin:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $container = new Container('session');
        $mainLayout = $this->layout();
        $mainLayout->setVariable('foo', 'bar'); //it accepts array too 
        return new ViewModel(array('username' => $container->username,
                               'password' => $container->password));
    }
}
```

In layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->foo ;?> // or just $foo
```

As a side note use plugins and view helpers for displaying user name or other user related stuff especial if your user is logged in. Check Zend\Authentication and plugin identity() its in Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Identity.php and check out its factory in Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Service\IdentityFactory.php

You can always make your own identity plugin and use your custom factory to customize it.

Comment: This method requires Checks on both ends, controller and layout. What if no username is present? Like that controller would throw an error as well as the layout. Furthermore, doing this kind of stuff is not the task of a controller. Do you really want to copy paste this stuff into every single action of every controller in your app? Because only then you'd have the variable available on every page... As pointed out in my comment - create a ViewHelper that does the job. It's way better design and much less troublesome ;)

Comment: @Sam did you see what i wrote as i side note? He was asking about passing variable to main layout and after that i also pointed out that using this method for authentication is not good and he should use plugins and helpers for that.

Comment: @kilop granted i overread your sidenote, since i can't undo the vote without an editted answer, i can only up the comment, gomen nasai!